# How to have my ViewController use a different storyboard? xCode 6.3

Tags: xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I duplicated a storyboard, and changed colors is all. What do I need to do to link my ViewController to use this other storyboard?  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your project folder in the navigation window. Under the Deployment Info section, click on the "Main Interface" text field and select your alternate storyboard. This will set it as the initial interface at launch time. If you want to switch between the storyboards while the application is running, that's a little more complicated and not something I've had to figure out yet.
[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you Mark. to switch storyboards, I came across that in a google search fyi. Thank you again. Mike